# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested

Tags: angularjs, express

when i  send post request in `angularjs` to `express` , i would receive an error"

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/users/register. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access"

but i has already set `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` in express And what funny is when i send get request , it can work.

Comment: here is my simple code    var config = {params: {username: $scope.user.username}};
            $http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register', config).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert(data.message);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               alert("error");
            })
        };router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
    res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.send({message:'hello'});


});

Answer (score 0):

How about try this:

`res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

Answer (score 0):

Use addHeader method,

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

* in above line will allow access to all domains.

For allowing access to specific domain only:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://www.example.com");
```